# GrabCut - bgdModel & fgdModel empty - Assertion error

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am attempting image segmentation using GrabCut algorithm in OpenCV2.1 (C++)

Here my code:

```
Mat rgbWorkImage = imread(argv[1]);
Mat mask;
mask = Scalar(0);
Mat bgdModel, fgdModel;
Rect rect = Rect(Point(0,0), imageSize);
grabCut(rgbWorkImage, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 0, GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
grabCut(rgbWorkImage, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 2, GC_EVAL);
```

Unfortunately I am getting this runtime error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty()) in initGMMs, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvgrabcut.cpp, line 368
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvgrabcut.cpp:368: error: (-215) !bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty() in function initGMMs
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One case where that error could happen is when your image has zero for either its width or height (but not for both) because of this bug: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/691 (which seems to be fixed after OpenCV 2.1).

If the image dimensions are non zero, you should also check that the ROI rect:

- is not empty (`imageSize` has not a zero size) and
- doesn't cover the entire image.

`GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` marks all pixels outside the given rect as "background" and all pixels inside the rect as "probably foreground", and the assert expect that there is pixels in both foreground (or "probably foreground") and background (or "probably background") list.

Comment: I verified that, but the image that I am using has nonzero height and width.

Comment: @Mayank I completed my answer with the other possibilities.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, for me it was that my rectangle covered the entire image.

Answer (score 3):

@alexisdm is right,

my rect was rect = (0,0,img.shape[0],img.shape[1]) because I did not know, where foreground and background is.

The **solution** is not to cover the entire image by changing it to
rect = (1,1,img.shape[0],img.shape[1]).