# Can't seem to use 'GC_INIT_WITH_MASK' on OpenCV GrabCut

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `GrabCut` and the `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` mode. So far I can use `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` perfectly fine. I'm doing this in Xcode for iOS.

Here is the `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` part that works perfectly:

```
cv::Mat bgdmodel, fgdmodel, mask, appliedMask;
cv::Rect rect = cv::Rect(0,0, image.cols-10, image.rows-10); 
cv::grabCut(image,mask,rect,bgdmodel,fgdmodel,1,cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);

cv::compare(mask,cv::GC_PR_FGD,appliedMask,cv::CMP_EQ);

cv::Mat foreground(image.size(),CV_8UC3,
                   cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
image.copyTo(foreground, appliedMask);
```

Here is my separate try with `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` that I keep can't seem to figure out:

```
cv::Rect rect = cv::Rect(0,0, image.cols-10, image.rows-10);
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::ones(image.size(), CV_8UC1) * cv::GC_PR_FGD;
cv::Mat appliedMask, bgdmodel, fgdmodel;
cv::grabCut(image, mask, rect ,bgdmodel,fgdmodel,1,cv::GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);

cv::compare(mask,cv::GC_PR_FGD,appliedMask,cv::CMP_EQ);

cv::Mat foreground(image.size(),CV_8UC3,
                   cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
image.copyTo(foreground, appliedMask);
```

As you can see, my mask is simply set to all pixels as `GC_PR_FGD` so it should take the entire image basically. But my `grabCut` call is failing, giving errors:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty()) in initGMMs....opencv/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp, line 379
error: (-215) !bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty() in function initGMMs
```

Couldn't find any really relevant solutions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546787/339946) was close but I'm not using `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT`). Any help or insight appreciated. I'm suspecting my mask is bad here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Basically, grabCut doesn't seem to like it when you give it a mask with all same values like I did with:

```
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::ones(image.size(), CV_8UC1) * cv::GC_PR_FGD;
```

By changing some of the values in my mask matrix, I was able to get a result.

```
    cv::Rect area;
    area.x=10;  area.y=10;
    area.width=image.cols; area.height=image.rows;
    rectangle(mask, area, cv::Scalar(cv::GC_PR_BGD),-1,8,0);
```

Comment: This problem occurs in opencv python also and is corrected the same way, by making sure the mask has some background and foreground markings

Comment: @StefanFabian Your condescension is appreciated but misplaced. cv::GC_FGD is the flag for obvious foreground. I used cv::GC_PR_FGD which indicates possible foreground. So it actually does exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your time!